# name 'QTableWidgetItem' is not defined

Tags: python, qwidget

## I tried install all rquired libs`I tried install all rquired libs and Im so sorry I am new here,Im trying to show datas in database on that widget and this problem occurs`,I searched all others about that but could not find any issue

import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import mysql.connector
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog , QApplication , QLineEdit , QInputDialog

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

```
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 0, 721, 300))
    self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(7)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 300, 133, 20))
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
    self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 320, 133, 20))
    self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
    self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 340, 133, 20))
    self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
    self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 360, 133, 20))
    self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
    self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 380, 133, 20))
    self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
    self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 400, 133, 20))
    self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget,clicked=lambda:self.save())
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(193, 300, 91, 121))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 300, 47, 20))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 320, 47, 20))
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 340, 47, 20))
    self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
    self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 360, 47, 20))
    self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
    self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 380, 47, 20))
    self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
    self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 400, 47, 20))
    self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
    self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEdit_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 320, 133, 20))
    self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
    self.lineEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEdit_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 360, 133, 20))
    self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
    self.lineEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEdit_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 380, 133, 20))
    self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
    self.lineEdit_10 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEdit_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 400, 133, 20))
    self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName("lineEdit_10")
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget,clicked=lambda:self.edit())
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 300, 91, 121))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "sayı"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "merkez"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "sayac no"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "geliş"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "çıkış"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "fiyat-geliş"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "fiyat-çıkış"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "MERKEZ"))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SAYAC"))
    self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "GELİŞ"))
    self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ÇIKIŞ"))
    self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "GELİŞ-F"))
    self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ÇIKIŞ-F"))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
    
    
def save(self): 
    mydb=mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="Tu41893982790",
        database="deneme")
    mycursor=mydb.cursor()
    sql="INSERT INTO sayac(merkez,sayac_no,gelis_tarihi,cikis_tarihi,gelis_fiyati,cikis_fiyati) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    val=(str(self.lineEdit.text()),str(self.lineEdit_2.text()),str(self.lineEdit_3.text()),str(self.lineEdit_4.text()),str(self.lineEdit_5.text()),str(self.lineEdit_6.text()))
    
    mycursor.execute(sql,val)
    mydb.commit()
def edit(self): 
    mydb=mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="Tu41893982790",
        database="deneme")
    mycursor=mydb.cursor()
    sql=f"UPDATE sayac SET cikis_tarihi={self.lineEdit_8.text()},gelis_fiyati={self.lineEdit_9.text()},cikis_fiyati={self.lineEdit_10.text()} WHERE sayac_no={self.lineEdit_7.text()}"
    mycursor.execute(sql)
    mydb.commit()
def load_data(self):
    mydb=mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="Tu41893982790",
        database="deneme")
    mycursor=mydb.cursor()
    sql="SELECT * FROM sayac"
    mycursor.execute(sql)
    results=mycursor.fetchall()
    results.reverse()
    results=list(results)
    row=0
    for sayac in results:
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row,0,QtWidgets,QTableWidgetItem(sayac[0]))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row,1,QtWidgets,QTableWidgetItem(sayac[1]))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row,2,QtWidgets,QTableWidgetItem(sayac[2]))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row,3,QtWidgets,QTableWidgetItem(sayac[3]))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row,4,QtWidgets,QTableWidgetItem(sayac[4]))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row,5,QtWidgets,QTableWidgetItem(sayac[5]))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row,6,QtWidgets,QTableWidgetItem(sayac[6]))
        row+=1
```

if **name** == "**main**":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that this problem occurs because of 'for sayac in results:' when it is removed,no problem but ı need this loop